# Simple tool for visualizing ideas and creating mockups

Tags: gratis, visual-design

I'm looking for free software, which is simple and easy to use and is good for visualization and mockups. So far I have used very basic tools like combination of paint and notepad. Hope that someone knows some good free software and can recommend it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/55182/prototyping-software-for-desktop-applications

Comment: Also if you search the forum, you will find a few other altermatives https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=mockup